# http://IP Address works with a different IP address

Tags: windows, server, ip

I have a windows server with IP address 10.90.3.141. When I enter http://10.90.3.141 in the browser, I get a "The page can't be displayed" error instead of the IIS default web page. However, when I enter http://10.90.3.151 (which is a different IP address) or localhost in the browser, then the IIS default web page is displayed. So basically:

http://10.90.3.141 which is the server IP address does not work
http://10.90.3.151 which is a different IP address works

I should expect it to be the other way round where http://10.90.3.141 works and http://10.90.3.151 does not work.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: windows server.